# Ms Access pop-up forms off screen

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am currently working in MS access 2013, and having an issue with some forms that worked previously.  I have gone back and edited them to have different functionality.  I need the forms to be pop ups.  Now, they work perfectly when they aren't pop-ups, but as soon as I change the forms to pop-ups the forms pop up off screen.  I have no clue how to fix this.

Now the first thing I did was start from an old verison, and I was just going to remake the form; however, as soon as I change ONE thing from those old forms the form starts popping up off screen again.

Has anyone had this issue or know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have two monitors or if your application is created in a secondary monitor and used in a single monitor machine, this behavior is expected. As EvDev mentioned. Set the "auto center" = Yes and edit your application in the default monitor.

Comment: I was working on dual monitors and that seems to be the issue.  I took a copy of the original database and pasted the necessary forms, queries, and subforms into their while working on the MAIN monitor and that seems to have solved the issue!  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Set the Auto Center property of the form to True.

Comment: I tried that, and it still is popping off the screen.  Thank you though!

Comment: Weird that mixed it for me.  What happens when you create a new pop up form?  Is it also off screen?

Comment: I hadn't tried that, but krish's thing seemed to fix it.  It had something to do with creating it in the secondary monitor I think.  Regardless it is fixed.  I just took the forms I edited and put them into the backup of my database (after backing that up first of course).